# Is there any workaround for glibc (2.28) compilation for very old kernel (older than 3.2.0) using --enable-kernel=VERSION?

Tags: linux, kernel, cross-compiling, glibc

I'm trying to cross-compile (from x86_64 linux to ARMv7a) for certain applications. The host was running Linux 4.4.0 and the target was running Linux 3.0.2

I was able to successfully build such application using cross-compile toolchain from Linaro
However, the problem occurred when I executed the binary

> Fatal: kernel too old

After some researchs on the Internet, I discovered that workaround would be to also cross-compile glibc as well with --enable-kernel=VERSION option and another problem came with this option.

> configure: WARNING: minimum kernel version reset to 3.2.0

Is there any workaround to set kernel version to the one older than 3.2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any workaround to set kernel version to the one older than 3.2.0?

No. Support for kernels below 3.2 [was dropped](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2016-08/msg00212.html) in glibc-2.24, and you can't bring it back (short of reverting the commits that did it).

You will need to build glibc-2.23 or older.